# Yii2, как очистить кэш(disk cache)

Tags: php, yii2, кэширование

Я заливаю обновления стилей и JS на production, очищаю папки frontend/web/assets и frontend/runtime/cache, очищаю кэш который на сервере, убираю кэш через консоль `php yii cache/flush-all`, но ничего не изменяется.(но изминения принимаються , если открыть в инкогнито)
Файлы кэшируются в disk cache

Как мне очистить кэш, чтобы принялись изминения.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что у Вас или не очищается кэш браузера или включено кэширование на стороне серверного стека.

Первое обычно решается при помощи <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> или окна настроек браузера. Со вторым лучше обратиться к своему сисадмину или девопсу, который поднимал стек на сервере или техподдержке хостинга.

Comment: (по поводу cntrl + f5 это само собой, забыл написать в вопросе)Общался с тех.поддержкой хостинга, сказали что очищали кэш,но нихера. Прочел статью, что https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/caching-http/, может что то с этим связанно?